# error bars are aligned incorrectly with columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can somebody assist me with this problem? The error bars are not aligned with the columns properly.

```
 ggplot (data=nitrate_meso00, aes(x = Date, 
                               y = mean_rr, 
                               fill = treatment,
                               ymin = lci_rr+mean_rr,
                               ymax =uci_rr+ mean_rr)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank ()) +
  # manually setting the width means we will have to tell geom_errorbar() about the new width
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 8) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")+
  geom_errorbar(width = 8,position = position_dodge(0.5))
```

[image: The produced graph:]

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772250/ggplot2-bars-non-aligned-to-error-bars

Comment: Hi there, you likely need to post your data for folks to help. Try using `dput(nitrate_meso00)` or some other method to provide your structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 - Bars non-aligned to error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772250/ggplot2-bars-non-aligned-to-error-bars)

Comment: I think OP's use of `fill = treatment` in the initial `ggplot(aes())` call implements the solution in the question above. The remaining problem I think is in the relative displacement of bars and error bars from the centre (as demonstrated below). Very handy to note though that grouping them does indeed line up dodged elements correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the width in `position_dodge` would need to be equal to your bar width to match the displacement?

Here's an example using completely simulated data - as suggested above if you can post a sample of your own data it would be possible to test if this is what's producing the problem in your case.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = rep(1:10, each = 2),
       a = rep(c("a", "b"), 10),
       y = rnorm(20, 20, 5)) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(sd = sd(y),
         ymin = y - sd,
         ymax = y + sd) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x,
    y,
    fill = a,
    ymin = ymin,
    ymax = ymax
  )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge",
           width = 0.75) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

[image]

In this example, setting the `width` arguments of `geom_bar` and `position_dodge` to 0.75 lines them up. Error bar width is independent of these.

<sup>Created on 2022-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>